# pass an array to json format in rails for autocomplete jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, autocomplete

I'm trying to have an autocomplete text field on a rails application. My issue concerns a customized data source.

Here's how I get the data: 
I look for the contact name, the id and add a category to show it on the autocomplete using [this example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#categories)

If the user is a friend, the category is contacts, otherwise the category is others

```
@result = Array.new
# find the current user id when its viewed as a contact
@current_contact = Contact.find_by_user_id(current_user).id
#go through all the contacts
Contact.order('name ASC').each do |a|
  #if the current contact is a friend of the user
  if Relationship.find_by_user_id_and_contact_id(current_user, a)
    #add it to the array with the 'contacts' category
    @result << [a.name, a.id, 'contacts']
  else
    #if its not a friend, and its not himself, add it to the array with the 'others' category
    unless @current_contact == a.id
      @result << [a.name.to_s,a.id, 'others']
    end
  end
end
```

How do i output this format so the autocomplete function can take it as a data source?

The example shows the format i'm looking for, which it seem to be json format

```
var data = [
{ label: "andreas andersson", category: "People" },
{ label: "andreas johnson", category: "People" }
];
```

But I can't seem to convert my output to that one. I've tried

```
@result.to_json
```

var data = [["AL Tohtori",279,"others"],["Abat Karine",296,"others"]]

with

```
@result.map {|r| {:label => r[0], :value => r[1], :category => r[2] } }
```

i can't seem to have it either.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try combining the approaches:

```
@result.map {|r| {:label => r[0], :value => r[1], :category => r[2] } }.to_json
```

If that doesn't help it might be best to use a JSON view library like [JBuilder](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder). There is a good screencast about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/320-jbuilder).